# Parent scope not updating from select with ng-change from directive

Tags: angularjs, select, scope, parent, ng-options

I've seen a couple of articles on this but still can't figure it out.

I am unable to update the parent scope from the  within a directive. I have read the articles saying the scope value should not be primitive and instead it should be an object but still can't figure out why this is not working.

```
angular.module('moduleMihai').controller('someController',
    ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

            $scope.durations = [{
                field: 'yearly',
                title: 'Yearly'
            }, {
                field: 'monthly',
                title: 'Monthly'
            }, {
                field: 'weekly',
                title: 'Weekly'
            }];
            $scope.selectedDuration = $scope.durations[0];

            $scope.handleDurationSelection = function () {
                console.log($scope.selectedDuration.field + ' selected');
                $scope.someData.title[0] = "SOMETHING ELSE!!";
            };


            $scope.someData= {
                title: ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'] };
}]);
```

the directive doesn't have any stuff in it:

```
angular.module("awaCommon").directive("durationSelection", [
    function () {
        return { 
            scope: {}, // tried removing this as well as seen in some articles 
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "duration-selection.html",
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

below the duration-selection.html which contains the select:

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
<div>
    Child: {{someData.title[0]}}
    <select
        ng-options="item.title for item in durations"
        ng-model="selectedDuration"
        ng-change="handleDurationSelection()">
    </select>
</div>
```

So this value above in the  Child: {{someData.title[0]}} - gets updated properly when value is selected. But the one in here -  Parent: {{someData.title[0]}}, in the main route is not:

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
<div>
    Parent: {{someData.title[0]}}
    <duration-selection></duration-selection>
</div>
```

I need the parent scope to be updated in order to update different directives

Comment: For Angular v1, use the `angularjs` tag. The `angular` tag is for Angular v2+. That way you'll catch the attention of the appropriate viewers.

Comment: ok sure, will do thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to interact and update your parent scope from your directive is to use

- event handling (emit and broadcast) [Todd about events $emit and $broadcast](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/) : so here we alert the parent when there is a change from the child directive, then the parent listens for the event. ***I suggest minimal usage due to some bad sides***
- directive attribute to pass the function: we pass our function to be processed to our directive to handle or call it when needed from the directive **( for me the best method)**
- inside the directive to update the $scope.$parent.lngBusinessUnit, no need to pass the function to the directive again, not necessary. since the directive is the one handling the logic. we just directly update the parent straight up.
- the use of $watch on the parent directive to help check for changes of the **selectedDuration** [$watch read more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope): this is quite easy since we map the ngModel to the passed param of our directive using two way binding in our return->scope **"="** from directive setup

**Example For each of the above possibilities**

- **Event Handling**

```js
angular.module("eventTest", [])
.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope){
  console.log("am here");
$scope.parentValue = "test";
$scope.valueToPass = ["Male", "Female"];


//let's catch the updated content
$scope.$on('childUpdated', function(event, value){
  $scope.parentValue = value;
  console.log("updated from child directive", value);
});


})
.directive("child", function(){
return {
  restrict:'E',
  scope: {
  valueToPass:"="
  },
  templateUrl:"child.html",
  controller: function ($scope){
  //this is method is triggered when the select of our valueToPass is changed
  $scope.childChanges = function (value){
      $scope.$emit('childUpdated', value);
      console.log("child emitted this:", value);
   }
  }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="eventTest"> 
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<h1>Event Test Just for your case, advise you read up</h1>
Parent: <b>{{parentValue}}</b>
<br>
<child value-to-pass="valueToPass"></child>
</div>


<script type='text/ng-template' id="child.html">
Child value : <b>{{menu}}<b> <br>
<select ng-model="menu" ng-change="childChanges(menu)">
  <option ng-repeat="item in valueToPass">{{item}}</option>
</select>
</script>

</body>
```

- **directive attribute , using function**

```js
angular.module("eventTest", [])
    .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope){
      console.log("am here");
    $scope.parentValue = "test";
    $scope.primaryVariable = "Male";
    
    $scope.onChange = function (){
     $scope.parentValue = $scope.primaryVariable;
    }
   

    })
    .directive("child", function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
      primaryVariable:"=",
      callMe:"&"//note this syntax, check angular directive doc
      },
      templateUrl:"child.html",
      controller: function ($scope){
       $scope.valueToPass = ["Male", "Female"];
      //this is method is triggered when the select of our primaryVarible is changed
      $scope.childChanges = function (){
        $scope.callMe();
       }
      }
    }
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <body ng-app="eventTest"> 
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>Directive Function Passing</h1>
    Parent: <b>{{parentValue}}</b>
    <br>
    <child primary-variable="primaryVariable" call-me="onChange()"></child>
    </div>


    <script type='text/ng-template' id="child.html">
    Child value : <b>{{primaryVariable}}<b> <br>
    <select ng-model="primaryVariable" ng-change="childChanges()">
      <option ng-repeat="item in valueToPass">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
    </script>

    </body>
```

- **using scope.$parent**

```js
 angular.module("eventTest", [])
        .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope){
          console.log("am here");
        $scope.parentValue = "test";
        $scope.primaryVariable = "Male";
         

        })
        .directive("child", function(){
        return {
          restrict:'E',
          scope: {
          primaryVariable:"="
          },
          templateUrl:"child.html",
          controller: function ($scope){
           $scope.valueToPass = ["Male", "Female"];
          //this is method is triggered when the select of our primaryVarible is changed
          $scope.childChanges = function (){
            $scope.$parent.parentValue = $scope.primaryVariable;
           }
          }
        }
        });
```

```html
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

        <body ng-app="eventTest"> 
        <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <h1>Using $parent</h1>
        Parent: <b>{{parentValue}}</b>
        <br>
        <child primary-variable="primaryVariable"></child>
        </div>


        <script type='text/ng-template' id="child.html">
        Child value : <b>{{primaryVariable}}<b> <br>
        <select ng-model="primaryVariable" ng-change="childChanges()">
          <option ng-repeat="item in valueToPass">{{item}}</option>
        </select>
        </script>

        </body>
```

- Using the $watch

```js
angular.module("eventTest", [])
        .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope){
          console.log("am here");
        $scope.parentValue = "test";
        $scope.primaryVariable = "Male";
         
         $scope.$watch('primaryVariable', function(){
         $scope.parentValue = $scope.primaryVariable;
         
         });
         
        })
        .directive("child", function(){
        return {
          restrict:'E',
          scope: {
          primaryVariable:"="
          },
          templateUrl:"child.html",
          controller: function ($scope){
           $scope.valueToPass = ["Male", "Female"];
          }
        }
        });
```

```html
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

        <body ng-app="eventTest"> 
        <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <h1>using $watch</h1>
        Parent: <b>{{parentValue}}</b>
        <br>
        <child primary-variable="primaryVariable"></child>
        </div>


        <script type='text/ng-template' id="child.html">
        Child value : <b>{{primaryVariable}}<b> <br>
        <select ng-model="primaryVariable" ng-change="childChanges()">
          <option ng-repeat="item in valueToPass">{{item}}</option>
        </select>
        </script>

        </body>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: one more question actually. Can I use the same to update the parent of the parent for example?

Comment: didn't get your comment above, be a bit explicit

Comment: oh sorry, for example if I have nested directives each with its own controller/scope.